# Working with Solr configuration

Tags: indexing, solr, solrcloud, solrconfig

We are using solr for indexing in our project. Indexing is working fine as of now.
We need to work on scenario where solr is down for some reason. 
What should indexing process do then?
Is there way during solr restart we can inject some script to execute the backlog indexings?
Just share your experiences how you guys handled such scenarios.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's usually far easier to just retry indexing at a set interval, but how are you indexing content today? If Solr is down, not much can be done (except for keeping track of which entries hasn't been indexed so they can be indexed when Solr is back up) - running as a cluster will help mitigate downtime at least, but there's still the issue about connectivity between applications being down, etc.

Comment: We are currently running a standalone application. if solr is down, this app will log entries into DB So that when solr is up those objects can be indexed. We don't want to continue with this approach. Instead, we were looking for an ability where solr will execute some script by itself when it restarts. many desktop application have ability to execute or load dll's on init of it. Does solr provides something like this OOTB? or can we do some configurations to achieve this?

Comment: Usually you'll have a init script installed that is responsible for starting Solr when the server restarts or the daemon restarts - this is [usually a plain bash script file living on your server](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/taking-solr-to-production.html) (the location will depend on your distribution and installation). You can add anything you want to this file that is valid bash, so calling a custom script is done by inserting a single call there.

Comment: Ok Thanks, will check and work on that.